# how to build a iOS shortcut to open several web pages?

Tags: ios, shortcut

I am going to build a iOS shortcut to open two or more web pages on safari. I've came up with the following idea: but it is no good and will only open the first URL. I expected Safari to open two pages because I gave two urls Shortcuts app.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it with just a simple three steps shortcut, if you prefer. Just use `Text action` + `Get URLs from inputs` + `Open URLs`.

[image: Simple shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

Set your URLs to a variable, then, get this variable and open the URLs.
This will open the URLs in two tabs.

[image: Shortcut]